# Countdown using astrisk

Tags: html

Currently it shows smallest to biggest. I want it start from biggest to smallest, can't figure it out.
Current output of code

```
Sample run:

Input to text box: 3

Output in div:

[*]

[**]

[***]

And that’s all folks!
```

Desired output of code

```
Sample Run:

Input to text box: 3

Output in div:

[***]

[**

[*]

And that’s all folks!
```

```
<!doctype html>
<!—This code will produce a triangle of stars -->
<!-- ================================== -->
<html>
 <head>
 <title> Countdown </title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function Countdown() {
    var count, astrisk;
    i=1;
    //j=0;
    count = parseFloat(document.getElementById('countBox').value);
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = '';
    astrisk = '*'

    while (i<count) {
      j=0;
      while (j<i) {
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + astrisk ;
        j=j+1;
      }

      document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
      document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + '<br>';
      i=i+1;
    }
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + 'And that\'s all folks!' + '<br>';
  }
 </script>
</head>
 <body>
 <p>
 Start of the countdown:
 <input type="text" id="countBox" size=4 value=10>
 </p>
 <input type="button" value="Begin Countdown" onclick="Countdown();">
 <hr>
 <div id="outputDiv"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried flipping some variables, couldn't exactly get it to do what I want. Most of my attempts have led to my computer crashing, I feel like answer is there, but I can't exactly see it. code isn't properly formatted, spent 2 hours trying to indent correctly, and eventually I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the `input`, `button` and `p (output)`
2. Add `click event` to the `button`
3. When the `button` is clicked, get `input.value` **plus 1** since it's automatically decreased at the beginning of the `function`
4. Print to the DOM the asterisk repeated by the `value` (that is decreased every 1 second).
5. When the `value` reaches 0, clear the function.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let output = document.querySelector('p');

// Button onclick
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Save the run time (input value + 1) since it's automatically decreased at run-time
  let timesRun = Number(input.value) + 1;
  // Disable the button when it's counting
  btn.disabled = true;
  
  // Repeated function every 1 second
  let interval = setInterval(function(){
      // Decrease the run time 
      timesRun -= 1;
       
       // If reaches 0, clear the function 
      if(timesRun === 0){
          btn.disabled = false;
          clearInterval(interval);
          output.innerHTML = 'TIMEOUT';
      // Else? print the * repeated by times remain
      } else {
          output.innerHTML = '*'.repeat(timesRun);
      }
  }, 1000); 
});
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Countdown" />
<button>Start</button>

<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Updated with the following conditions:

1. Check that the `input` is a valid number and not empty
2. Accept a number between 1 and 10 (including)

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let output = document.querySelector('p');

// Button onclick
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Check it's a valid nubmer and not empty
  if(input.value.length === 0 || isNaN(Number(input.value))) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Please type a valid number.';
  // Check if the number is between 1 and 10
  } else if (Number(input.value) <= 0 || Number(input.value) > 10) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Please type a number between 1-10';
  } else {
    // Save the run time (input value + 1) since it's automatically decreased at run-time
    let timesRun = Number(input.value) + 1;
    // Disable the button when it's counting
    btn.disabled = true;
    // Repeated function every 1 second
    let interval = setInterval(function(){
        // Decrease the run time 
        timesRun -= 1;

         // If reaches 0, clear the function
        if(timesRun === 0){
            btn.disabled = false;
            clearInterval(interval);
            output.innerHTML = 'TIMEOUT';
        // Else? print the * repeated by times remain
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = '*'.repeat(timesRun);
        }
    }, 1000); 
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Countdown" />
<button>Start</button>

<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.